# "And what make you from Wittenberg, Horatio?"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, shakespeare

Here's from Hamlet, Act 1, Scene 2
(The Arden Shakespeare edited by Harold Jenkins)

> Hor. Hail to your lordship.
>
> Ham. I am glad to see you well.
>
> Horatio, or I do forget myself.
>
> Hor. The same, my lord, and your poor servant ever.
>
> Ham. Sir, my good friend, I'll change that name with you.
>
> And what make you from Wittenberg, Horatio?
>
> Marcellus.

I'm wondering what is the subject of the sentence:

> And what make you from Wittenberg, Horatio?

Is it "what" or "you"?
It seems to me that "what" is the subject, because Horatio answered:

> A truant disposition, good my lord.

However, I wonder why the "make" is not "makes" in that case.

Comment: I would say that this line means *What makes you from Wittenburg?*, so the subject would be *what* and the direct object *you* because something makes Horatio from Wittenburg (as opposed to Horatio making something from Wittenburg).

Comment: The *make* vs. *makes* is most likely wierd Shakespearian grammar.

Comment: I'm not exactly an expert on standard Elizabethan usages, but I suppose the sense of the question is *"What **causes** you to be away from Wittenberg?"*, which could refer to *multiple* causes. So perhaps it's based on an underlying *"What [reasons] make you [be away] from Wittenberg?"*.

Answer (score 3):

Hamlet asks what Horatio is making (= doing).

Horatio's answer plays on the multiple senses of *disposition*.

- Literally, it is an  "arrangement" or "plan"; Horatio responds that he is 'making' the sort of plans characteristic of truancy.
- More narrowly, it often means "living arrangements", as when Othello demands a suitable residence for Desdemona:

  > I crave fit disposition for my wife.

  So Horatio is looking for accommodations suitable to a student playing hookey.
- And in a figurative sense it means how a person's faculties and appetites are "arranged": a person's attitude and temperament. Horatio claims he is 'making' = acting out a natural disposition to idleness.

This sort of punning is characteristic of Hamlet's conversation, and his friends are all *disposed* to play up to it.

Comment: It seems that Shakespeare used the word "disposition" almost in modern sense.
Shakespeare's Language, Second Edition by Eugene F. Shewmaker
disposition, n. 1 one's nature; here, esp., mental stability:
"So horribly to shake our disposition/With thoughts beyond our reaches of our souls?"
Ham. I, iv, 55-56.
2 [often pl] inclination;
"How stands your dispositions to be married?" Rom. & Jul. I, iii, 65.
3 general quality; way of thinking and behaving:
"... to practice his judgement[experiment] with the disposition/of natures."
Meas. III, i, 162-163.

Comment: @ivanhoescott *Disposition* has the "arrangement" sense today, too: it is equivalent to *disposal*.

Comment: Do you know Shakespeare's other examples of "disposition" meaning "arrangement"?

Comment: @ivanhoescott No. *What make you?* is ordinary "What are you doing?", "What are you up to?". You'll find it again in 2.2: Hamlet asks R&G "What make you in Elsinore?" *AYLI*,1.1 "Now, sir, what make you here?", and 2.3 "Why, what make you here?"  *Oth*, 3.4 "What make you from home?"  *RIII*, 1.3 "What mak'st thou in my sight?"

Comment: @ivanhoescott I gave you one in the answer.

Comment: I mean other than the one in your answer.

Comment: @ivanhoescott I don't know of another; but so what? It's an attested use, and it's the sort of wordplay that Ham and Hor and R&G delight in. Undoubtedly the 'temperament, inclination' sense is there, too.

Comment: Not that I disagree with you.
I'm just not sure.
It is unlikely that Eugene Shewmaker missed the "disposition" in the sentence of my question,
because he must have used a computer to write the glossary.
If he did check the word in the sentence, then he obviously thought it did not mean "arrangement".